How to parse SMBios binary data with unexpected zeroes inside string area?
I wrote a simple parser to parse SMBios entries, and recently I got a morbid binary that breaks parsing procedure. The screenshot of hex editor opening this binary data is pasted below (with probable sensitive data masked).
According to the SMBios standard, each entry is composed to:

a structural part with specified length;
a nonstructural part with null-terminated strings. And an extra null byte indicating end of this part. Thus two continuous null bytes in this part would immediately start next entry.

In the screenshot below, first three entries are marked with green boxes. Near tail of the nonstructural part of the 3rd entry, there are multiple continuous null bytes (mark with red box). And visually we can see that immediately after these bytes, there are still valid string contents (No Enclosure etc.), and the actual beginning of the next entry is probably located after these strings (marked with blue cursor).
I find it very hard to work around these continuous zeroes. If I simply scan until reaching non-null bytes, how could I treat with with it?

If I treat them as the header of next entry, I will get type 0x4e and size 0x6f, which is invalid and will probably break all subsequent entry parsing.
If I treat it as continuing of strings part, what if it is actually not?

Any suggestions on it?


So in the final redacted section there weren't two consecutive 00 bytes? To be honest it looks like the problem started before the section identified in red. 04 03 03 03 03 of course is non zero, but it doesn't look like a string either. It looks like it might have been part of a separate SMBIOS entry? What was the source of this binary? Was the binary retrieved properly?
